# Sorting an object by a property holding an array value, not a string one

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Suppose I have data in the following format:

```
[
    {
        foo: "a",
        bar: 5,
        baz: [
            "qux doo",
            "adsf",
            "abcd",
            "zzzz",
            "898jwe9"
        ],
    },
            {
        foo: "f",
        bar: 4859,
        baz: [
            "abcd",
            "xxrwu",
            "urnr",
            "pupupu",
            "sdsdsd"
        ],
    },
]
```

Suppose that I wanted to sort this array by `foo`. This would be simple:

```
.sort(function(a, b){ return (a.foo < b.foo) - (a.foo > b.foo); });
```

But what if I wanted to sort it by `baz`? How would one do this?

Comment: What kind of logic are you looking for? How would you know which array should 'come first'?

Comment: The same way that you know with strings.

Comment: But they're not strings, are they. There are too many different ways that the arrays could be compared. Unless you're saying you want to compare them as though they were strings, in which case you'd  convert them to string, which your existing solution will do automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
.sort(function(a, b) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(a.baz.length, b.baz.length); i++) {
        if (a.baz[i] < b.baz[i]) return -1;
        if (a.baz[i] > b.baz[i]) return 1;
    } 
    return (a.baz.length > b.baz.length) - (a.baz.length < b.baz.length); 
});
```

Comment: Will this produce any difference in result whatsoever for any input case, than if I were to use: `.sort(function(a,b){ return (JSON.stringify(a.baz) < JSON.stringify(b.baz)) - (JSON.stringify(a.baz) > JSON.stringify(b.baz)); });`?

Comment: @user2958725 Yes, for example if the lengths of the lists differ.  It can also depend on the strings within the list, for example `"a-" < "a-b"`, but `'["a-"]' > '["a-b"]'`.